# Loop through a list in asp and post to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a ul of text boxes. I want to loop through the list elements and post their values to a database. How can I do this in asp?

```
Set dataCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsAwards = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Awards"
rsAwards.Open strSQL, dataCon

<form name="sort_award" action="action_awards.asp?Action=sort&Award_ID=<%=Award_ID%>" method="post">

response.write "<ul id='sortable'>"
  dim i
  i=0

    While not rsAwards.EOF

      response.write "<li onclick='sort()'><input type='text' id='AwardNum' size='1' value="&i&" ></li>"

      rsAwards.MoveNext
      i=i+1

    Wend 
response.write "</ul></form>"
```

Comment: this is your actual code? Where is the query ... and the connection objects ???

Comment: rsAwards is my recordset, my connection object is named dataCon

Comment: don't post it as comment , better edit your question and post **all related and relevant code**, to solve your problem

Comment: this is only a portion of my code.

Comment: you need a <form> tag to get your data in other page

Comment: Rafael, what I'm looking for is a loop that will post all the values of the text boxes within the unordered list. As you can see the list is populated dynamical from the database.

Comment: to retrive all the textbox values, you will need to enclose your list in a form and submit it. if you don't want to submit a form (i don't find any good excuse to not use a form), you could use ajax to send all the values.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with ajax, how could I use that instead?

Comment: The question is why you don't want to use a form?

Comment: I am using a form. The issue I am having is when I submit the form I am having trouble looping through the list items to obtain their values and then store them in my database.

Comment: then post in the question the code that you are using to get values after the submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible issues (not sure if these are actually problems or just an artifact of trimming your code):

- Your fields don't have names, so they aren't returning any values (an id is useless in this regard).
- ID attributes must be unique; you can't use "AwardNum" for all of them.
- You need to tell the form how many fields to look for.

```vbs
<form action="action_awards.asp?Action=sort&Award_ID=<%=Award_ID%>" method="post">
<%
dim i
i=0
'... display stuff omitted
While not rsAwards.EOF
    '- only fields with names can return any data
    response.write "<input type='text' name='A_" & i & "'"
    '- id attributes must be unique
    response.write " id='AwardNum_" & i & "' size='1' value='" & i & "'>"
    rsAwards.MoveNext
    i=i+1
Wend 
'- tell the form how many fields there are
response.write "<input type='hidden' name='N' value='" & i & "'>"
'- (I assume you have a submit button or some other method to submit the data?)
%>
</form>
```

To read this form, you'd do something like:

```vbs
dim N, V(), i
N = request.form("N")
redim V(N)
for i = 0 to N
    V(i) = request.form("A_" & i)
next
```

Another option would be to give all the fields the same name:

```vbs
response.write "<input type='text' name='Award' value='" & i & "'>"
```

This will give you a comma-delimited list of values, and you can use `Split()` to divvy them up.

```vbs
V = Request.Form("Award")
V = Split(V,", ")
for i = 0 to UBound(V)
   if V(i) <> "" then '... do stuff ...
next
```

Note that this approach is only recommended if the possible fields values (a) are pretty short, and (b) will never include commas. So it'll work for checkboxes, but it probably isn't the best method of dealing with text input fields, and it shouldn't even be considered for textareas.